# How do I extract random effects from MCMCglmm?

Tags: r, bayesian, mcmc

I am looking for a command similar to `ranef()` used in nlme, lme4, and brms that will allow me to extract the individual random effects in my MCMCglmm model. In my dataset, I have 40 providers and I would like to extract the random effects for each provider and plot them in a caterpillar plot. Any suggestions would be great. Thank you.

In case it is helpful, here is my MCMCglmm model:

```
prior.3 <- list(R = list(R1 = list(V = diag(2), nu = 0.002)), 
                G = list(G1 = list(V = diag(2), nu = 0.002), 
                         G2 = list(V = diag(2), nu = 0.002))) 

mc_mod2 <- MCMCglmm(outcome ~ 1, data = filter(data, rem2 == "white" | rem2 == "rem"),
                  random = ~ idh(rem2):id + us(rem2):provider,
                  rcov = ~idh(rem2):units,
                  verbose = TRUE,
                  prior = prior.3,
                  family = "gaussian",
                  nitt = 100000, burnin = 5000,
                  pr = TRUE)
```

Comment: https://rdrr.io/github/JWiley/postMCMCglmm/man/ranef.MCMCglmm.html ?

Comment: I tried that using `ranef(mc_mod2)` and I am thrown the following error: `Error in UseMethod("ranef") : no applicable method for 'ranef' applied to an object of class "MCMCglmm"`

Comment: did you install that package and load it?

Comment: blast... i overlooked the package name on that site and assumed it was mcmcglmm. many thanks, ben.

Answer (score 11):

A little more detail, since the package doesn't seem to have caterpillar plots built in: note you need to use `pr=TRUE` when calling `MCMCglmm` in order to store the random effects values.

```
library(MCMCglmm)
data(PlodiaPO)  
model1 <- MCMCglmm(PO~1, random=~FSfamily, data=PlodiaPO, verbose=FALSE,
                 nitt=1300, burnin=300, thin=1,
                 pr=TRUE)
if (!require("postMCMCglmm")) {
    devtools::install_github("JWiley/postMCMCglmm")
    library("postMCMCglmm")
}
```

`ranef()` appears to return a matrix of the random effects (rows=levels, columns=samples). Convert to a data frame with mean and quantiles:

```
qfun <- function(x,lev) unname(quantile(x,lev))
rsum <- as.data.frame(t(apply(ranef(model1),1,
      function(x) c(est=mean(x),
                    min=qfun(x,0.025),max=qfun(x,0.975)))))
```

Order for plotting:

```
rsum$term <- reorder(factor(rownames(rsum)),
                     rsum$est)
```

Plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(rsum,aes(term,est))+
    geom_pointrange(aes(ymin=min,ymax=max))+
    coord_flip()
```

[image]

Comment: This is fantastic... Thank you, Ben. My only issue is that the `ranef` function does not seem to work when I specify my random effects as so: `random = ~ idh(rem2):id + us(rem2):provider` ... my intention is to extract random effects at the client and provider status based on client's racial-ethnic minority status (white/non-white). When I call only `id` and `provider` random effects, the ranef function works great, but when I stratify them based on REM status, the ranef function outputs an empty matrix. Any ideas?

Comment: Ultimately, the goal is to have a random effect output that looks similar to: provider_1_white, provider_1_rem, provider_2_white, provider_2_rem, etc. Maybe this isn't possible?

Comment: I found a solution... when random effects are stratified (as shown in my model above) the `ranef()` function in postMCMCglmm will not work (at least as of this writing). but they can be extracted manually by using `str(mc_mod2)` and then put in a readable format using `cbind(B = posterior.mode(mc_mod2$Sol[,1:50]), CI = HPDinterval(mc_mod2$Sol[,1:50]))`

Answer (score 0):

I overlooked an additional package that needed to be installed (thanks for pointing this out, Ben).

To be able to run `ranef()`, simply install the postMCMCglmm package - https://github.com/jwiley/postMCMCglmm/

```
#install.packages("devtools")
require(devtools)

install_github("JWiley/postMCMCglmm")
```